# Trigger hidden Button doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a hidden button. Unfortunately the event does not work. Here is the code:

```
<div class="dyn-inp-group">
  <div class="dyn-inps">
          <div class="form-group form-group-options col-xs-12 dyn-inp">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;">
              <input class="form-control" class="customerfirstName" name="customer[firstName][]" type="text" placeholder="First name" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="entry input-group col-md-6" style="margin: 0;">
              <input class="form-control" name="customer[lastName][]" type="text" placeholder="Last name" required="required">
              <span class="input-group-btn hidden">
                <button id="remove"  class="btn btn-info btn-remove" type="button">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group form-group-options col-xs-12 dyn-btn">
          <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
            <button id="countInput" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add  more
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>
```

I am counting all the inputs when you click to the "add button".

```
 var customerCount= 1 ;
$( "#countInput" ).click(function() {
 var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var i ;
var s = 1 ;

for(i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
if(e[i].type== "text" && e[i].name=="customer[firstName][]" ) { s++  ; }}
 customerCount=s;
});
```

I have also a button for remove. The remove button does not work. When I click to the remove button I want to count the input fields again.

```
$( "#countInput" ).click(function() { This does not work
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you possibly using the wrong selector for your remove button? should it be `$( "#remove" ).click(function() {`?

Comment: can we see your css? also, do you have any jsfiddle with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem. both the button clicks are working fine

```
$( "#countInput" ).click(function()
$( "#remove" ).click(function()
```

check here: https://jsfiddle.net/ucnh4z4q/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using JQuery you can use .each() instead of mixing pure js with JQuery defining a lot of useless variables

```
var customerCount= 1 ;

$('#countInput').click(function() {
    $('input').each(function(item) {
    var newCustomer;
    if($(this).attr('name') === 'customer[firstName][]')
        customerCount+=1;
  });
    console.log(customerCount);
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
    customerCount-=1;
  console.log(customerCount);
});
```

[Here a working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/k9fwrvtd/)